# Add padding only to elements on the right css with dynamic content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a WordPress website with a custom post type that I need to display in a Bootstrap grid.
Here's what I mean :

[image: Bootsrap grid]

I need to create a gutter in the center, but obviously if I add a padding-left, it moves every element. I only need to add padding to the item on the right. Since the content is dynamic, I can't just add a class and type

```
.right-elements { padding-left: 10px; }
```

Is there a CSS property for even elements or something ?

( since the issue is not really unique I don't feel like I should add the code, but tell me if you need it )

Thanks !

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 ( have to add characters )

Comment: With Btp 4 you can use [cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in modifying even elements, you can use the [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) rule:

```
.my-class:nth-child(even) { padding-left: 10px; }
```

Comment: Well I just tried that, and a padding-left of 10px and it actually goes further left

Comment: What about reversing the rule to `.my-class:nth-child(odd) { padding-right: 10px; }`. Does that make a difference? It's hard to know without a working example we can look at.

Comment: Nevermind I added padding to a div that had p-b-4, so using padding-left:10px; actually decreased the padding, I added it to the .row inside it and it works, thanks a lot :)